# How to convert non-printable character or string to hex?

Tags: java, string, hex

I have String which contain the next hex presentation:
"5f e8 d0 7b c0 f7 54 07 fb e4 20 f5 b8 10 67 a9"

You understand that this is just hex and I need to get this hex presentation from String. String looks like:
"ED>@@2.W.W'KJ%z_{T g"

So, how to get from "ED>@@2.W.W'KJ%z_{T g" hex presentation "5f e8 d0 7b c0 f7 54 07 fb e4 20 f5 b8 10 67 a9"? This is unprintable characters so I can't use this:

    `public static String stringToHex(String arg) {
        return String.format("%x", new BigInteger(arg.getBytes()));
    }`

result: -10404282104042104042104042104042104042c7eea21040428189104042104042f5.
And also this returns me something strange:

`System.out.println(String.format("%h", Integer.toHexString(buff.charAt(0))));`

result: 6d1.

And this code sometimes works. The data comes from socket (as String because I need to get many answers as String and only this Auth Challenge as hex).

Comment: What does this give? `System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(buff.charAt(0)));`

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you have a String which contains the character "5", followed by "f", followed by a space, followed by "e", etc., or do you have a String which contains the bytes 0x5F, 0xE8, etc.?

Comment: I have String with unprintable characters. The hex upper is hexademical presentation of the String.

Comment: fd, «6d1» is the result of call.

Comment: Right, sorry, that wasn't at all clear, since you started with "I have a String which contains..."

Comment: Also, it's not at all clear how "E" maps to 0x5F and "D" maps to 0xE8. Unless you're using a character encoding such as EBCDIC (which this isn't - I checked). Also, "W" appears in the input string twice, but there doesn't appear to be any repeating groups in the required output. If I had a bit more rep, I'd be voting to close this question...

Comment: sigh. You converted data from a socket (bytes) to a String (chars) and want to recreate the data? Your data has already been corrupted. String encodes `char`s using `byte`s. Depending on your platforms default encoding, some multi-byte sequences have already been eaten and turned into single `char`s. In c/c++ char:=byte. In Java they are not.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to use byte array type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct solution:

```
public static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {  
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b: bytes) {
        out.append(String.format("%02X", b) + " ");
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

Solution with `Integer.toHexString()` is wrong for the following reasons:

1. It doesn't add leading zero to bytes 0x01 - 0x0F
2. It prints bytes 0x80 - 0xFF as negative integers in 2's complement representation

Comment: Why not add the space inside the format string `"%02X "` ?