# Print String with escape non printable characters

Tags: java

I have this String

```
String x="String containning special chars  \u202C \n  \u202C  \u202C  \u202C";
```

How can I print out this: `String containning special chars  \u202C \n  \u202C  \u202C  \u202C` ?

Tried

```
System.out.println(x.replace("\\","\\\\"));
```

But that only prints `String containning special chars  ‬ \n ‬  ‬  ‬`

Also tried

```
String out = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(x);
System.out.println(out);
```

But that also doesn't help.

Any one with a suggestion or an API that I am not aware of?

**UPDATE - SOLUTION**

Following @lbear aproach I came up with this functions that deals most cases of escaped Strings

```
public static String removeUnicodeAndEscapeChars(String input) {
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if ((int) input.charAt(i) > 256) {
            buffer.append("\\u").append(Integer.toHexString((int) input.charAt(i)));
        } else {
            if (input.charAt(i) == '\n') {
                buffer.append("\\n");
            } else if(input.charAt(i) == '\t'){
                buffer.append("\\t");
            }else if(input.charAt(i) == '\r'){
                buffer.append("\\r");
            }else if(input.charAt(i) == '\b'){
                buffer.append("\\b");
            }else if(input.charAt(i) == '\f'){
                buffer.append("\\f");
            }else if(input.charAt(i) == '\''){
                buffer.append("\\'");
            }else if(input.charAt(i) == '\"'){
                buffer.append("\\");
            }else if(input.charAt(i) == '\\'){
                buffer.append("\\\\");
            }else {
                buffer.append(input.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: did you try this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787769/how-to-convert-non-printable-character-or-string-to-hex

Comment: @DevZer0 how can this be of any help to me?

Comment: I also see this earlier post, but it totally does not work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535317/how-to-replace-with-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Integer.toHexString((int)x.charAt(34));`, you can get the string of the unicode char, and add `\\u` before it, you will get the `String`.

```
public static String removeUnicode(String input){
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(input.length());
    for (int i =0; i < input.length(); i++){
        if ((int)input.charAt(i) > 256){
        buffer.append("\\u").append(Integer.toHexString((int)input.charAt(i)));
        } else {
            if ( input.charAt(i) == '\n'){
                buffer.append("\\n");
            } else {
                buffer.append(input.charAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: so what exactly should I supply to `System.out.print()` to get the desired result?

Comment: What you did here is you processed unicode characters and newline. what about all the others? This is basically the same as the others answer it just processes unicode characters all together that is almost okay, but there MUST be a general solution, remember all that needs to be done is to replace \ with \\

Comment: @MaVRoSCy I have fixed it. Please try it again.

Comment: @MaVRoSCy a Unicode character is regarded as one single char. When we use `replace()`, it can find \ leading the unicode char.

Answer (score 4):

There is the [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) which has HTML encoding. This encoding is pretty close to what you may need

```
String escaped code = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(rowId)
```

[See doc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)

Comment: StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(rowId);  // must have been added since 2013.

Comment: Deprecated since 3.6. We should switch to org.apache.commons:commons-text which got [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
String original = "String containning special chars  \u202C \n  \u202C  \u202C  \u202C";
String escaped = original.replace("\u202C", "\\u202C");
System.out.println(escaped);
```

Comment: I would personally like to be interested in a more general solution.

Comment: yeap, actually to be correct I would use `original.replace("\u202C", "\\u202C").replace("\n", "\\n");`  but I am looking for a more general solution